# mysql returns same result from any distance paramter

Tags: php, mysql

I have a very strange problem.
http://meineanzeige24.de/androidApp/ilanImages/0/10/0.9148%2C32.86342555
this url is the rest url that i use for searching items on db according to their lat,long user lat,long and distance.

my query got changed by the url for example when i change 10 to 1000 , search query try to search distance < 1000.

you can see the query results on the link
http://meineanzeige24.de/androidApp/ilanImages/0/10/0.9148%2C32.86342555

The problem is that when i change distance and paste the query to the phpmyadmin and run the query, query works

but

on the page when i change distance to any integer value, on the web results are always same.Moreover distance<10 shows all items.you can try it by playing the query.But as i said it works when i paste to phpmyadmin.

php code is here, i use mysqlliDB.php for mysqlconnection
waiting for your help.

```
        function getIlanImages($catId,$rangeKM,$location) {
    global $host,$user,$password,$db_name;
    global $db;

    $loc = explode(',', $location);

    if($catId>0)
    {


        $q2 = "Select lat,lon,Id,resim1,kategoriId,(     DEGREES(ACOS(COS(RADIANS($loc[0])) * COS(RADIANS(lat)) *             COS(RADIANS($loc[1]) - RADIANS(lon)) +             SIN(RADIANS($loc[0])) * SIN(RADIANS(lat))))    )*111.045 as distance from (SELECT SUBSTRING( map, 2, INSTR(map,',')-2) AS lat, SUBSTRING( map, INSTR(map,',')-length(map),length(map)-INSTR(map,',')-4) AS lon,Id,resim1,kategoriId FROM  firmalar   ) as tbl  WHERE kategoriId=$catId  HAVING distance <= $rangeKM ORDER BY distance";
    }
    else
    {


        $q2 = "Select distance,Id,resim1 from (Select lat,lon,Id,resim1,(     DEGREES(ACOS(COS(RADIANS($loc[0])) * COS(RADIANS(lat)) *             COS(RADIANS($loc[1]) - RADIANS(lon)) +             SIN(RADIANS($loc[0])) * SIN(RADIANS(lat))))    )*111.045 as distance from (SELECT SUBSTRING( map, 2, INSTR(map,',')-2) AS lat, SUBSTRING( map, INSTR(map,',')-length(map),length(map)-INSTR(map,',')-4) AS lon,Id,resim1 FROM  firmalar   ) as tbl) as d WHERE d.distance <= $rangeKM ORDER BY distance"; 
        $result = $db->rawQuery($q2, null); 
    }
    echo $q2; 

   if ($db->count == 0) {
        return "herhangi bir mesaj yok";
    }
    return json_encode($result);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is about the mysqldb.php class
https://github.com/joshcam/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class
rawquery function not returns correct results
I use core php mysql functions